# SQLServerBulkCopy PostgreSQL to MS-SQL Server for NVARCHAR

Tags: java, sql-server, nvarchar, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to use [SQLServerBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) for migrating data from PostgreSQL to MS-SQL Server. I am facing problem for non-English characters (Unicode). To store these data, in PostgreSQL `text` datatype and for MS-SQL, `nvarchar` is used.

This is the code snippet

```
public class MssqlBulkLoad {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        String sql = "select id, data::varchar from test_data";

        Connection pgConn = getPgConnection();
        Statement pgStmt = pgConn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        pgStmt.setFetchSize(200);

        Connection sqlServerConn = getSQLServerConnection();
        SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(sqlServerConn);
        bulkCopy.setBulkCopyOptions(options());
        bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName("TEST_DATA2");

        ResultSet pgResultSet = pgStmt.executeQuery(sql);
        printMeta(pgResultSet);

        bulkCopy.writeToServer(pgResultSet);

        pgResultSet.close();
        bulkCopy.close();
        sqlServerConn.close();
        pgStmt.close();
        pgConn.close();
    }

    private static void printMeta(ResultSet pgResultSet) throws SQLException {
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = pgResultSet.getMetaData();
        int c = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnType(i) + "\t" + rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
        }
    }

    private static SQLServerBulkCopyOptions options() throws SQLException {
        SQLServerBulkCopyOptions options = new SQLServerBulkCopyOptions();
        options.setBulkCopyTimeout(60000);
        options.setKeepIdentity(true);
        options.setBatchSize(50);
        return options;
    }
}
```

The newly migrated data is in an unknown format, see below

[image]

But, the actual data should be as shown below.

[image]

In my Java code, to select data from PostgreSQL, I tried using simple select query, `select * from test_data` but I am getting exception

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Data type other is not supported in bulk copy.

From this, it seems that when selecting data of `text` datatype, the type of the column in ResultSet is `Types.OTHER`. So, to avoid about mentioned exception, I case text type to `varchar`, which returns types as `Types.VARCHAR`.

I am using sqlserver-jdbc driver 7.0.0

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Could this be a collation mismatch?  What is the collation specified (or defaulted) in your Postgresql DB and what is it in SQL Server?

Comment: One thing you could do is use use SSIS.  See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2619/export-data-from-postgres-to-sql-server-using-ssis/

Comment: @user1443098 I cant use SSIS.

Comment: Why can't you use it?  Do you need training, or other help?

Comment: I didn’t mean like that. We will be using it for an automated process. So we need to integrate a java based solution into our product.

Comment: SSIS shines at automated processes.  Used by thousands of businesses every day for that (I don't work for Microsoft!)  You know you can call SSIS from an .NET application, right?

Comment: @user1443098 Collation of SQL Server is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and PostgreSQL is `English_India.1252`. Also, I haven't looked into .net side for this current problem because, we cant incorporate .net into our current design. For this reason only I am looking into Java BulkCopy.

Comment: Have you tried the collation Latin1_General_100_CI_AS?  See more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: In the default collation itself, when inserting data via SQL, it works fine (refer the snapshot attached)

Comment: Have you tried casting "other" to NVARCHAR? assuming you may need unicode

Comment: I hope you mean in the select query which is getting executed in Postgres. If that's the case, in Postgres there is nothing specific for nvarchar. So I can't directly cast it to nvarchar.

Comment: I mean when building the bulk copy command.  You should be able to specify the target datatypes and collations

Comment: @user1443098 I can't find any such Java API . Can you direct me to that API

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180223/discussion-between-user1443098-and-suraj1291993).